# How to account for multiple basket views in Google Analytics conversion funnel?

Tags: google, analytics, ecommerce, goal-tracking, checkout

Assuming a typical ecommerce sales funnel of:

*1. add to basket*
*2. browse more products*
*3. add (again) to basket*
*4. checkout*
*5. confirmation page*

How does one account for the multiple visits to the basket page? I.e. this would give 2x pageviews for the basket page for a single checkout = 50% funnel conversion rate. Each time the customer returns to the product catalogue from the basket, your funnel conversion rate is reduced!

Is there any way of accounting for this in Google Analytics? Or is this just a rubbish metric?

Answer (score 1):

My bad...it is apparent that the number given in Google Analytics is the 'Unique Pageviews' metric for the basket page, and not the total pageviews, which does account for multiple visits.

I.e. if the same customer visits the basket twice in a session, it's only counted once; but (importantly) if they visit in another session, this is counted again.